# Is it possible to update multiple rows with Quill using IN

Tags: quill.io

It is possible to produce something like

```
UPDATE employees SET gender = 'Male' WHERE id IN ('asfd','bleh');
```

with Quill? I don't find and example in the documentation, and [batch update seems to be something else](https://getquill.io/#quotation-actions-batch-update).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me (try on https://scastie.scala-lang.org/):

Static query:

```
import io.getquill._

val ctx = new SqlMirrorContext(PostgresDialect, SnakeCase)

import ctx._

case class Product(name: String, price: Int)

def products(names: Seq[String], name: String) =
    ctx.run {
      ctx
        .query[Product]
        .filter(person => quote(liftQuery(names).contains(person.name)))
        .update(_.name -> lift(name))
}

val m = products(Seq("AA", "BB"), "EE")

println(m.string)
```

Dynamic query

```
import io.getquill._

val ctx = new SqlMirrorContext(PostgresDialect, SnakeCase)

import ctx._

case class Product(name: String, price: Int)

def products(names: Seq[String], name: String) =
    ctx.run {
      ctx
        .dynamicQuery[Product]
        .filter(person => quote(liftQuery(names).contains(person.name)))
        .update(setValue(_.name, name))
}

val m = products(Seq("AA", "BB"), "EE")

println(m.string)
```

Output:

`UPDATE product SET name = ? WHERE name IN (?, ?)`